# Where is the best place to add breakpoints in the code for debugging?

Tags: javascript, debugging

I'm still very much in the learning phase of programming, I have a long way to go before I might actually be ready to try and do it as a career. But I'm practicing debugging. Need some help breaking down how to debug this code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Clicker</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
</head>
<body>
  <button>Click</button>

<script>
  const counter = {
    cnt: 0,

    inc: function() {
      cnt++;
      console.log(cnt)
    }
  };

  const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc(), false);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you looked at a debugging tutorial for JavaScript? There have to be *some* out there. In this case, read up on `this` and it's uses ;)

Comment: @Luca I'll check that out. Thanks!

Comment: "*I need some help.*" Where are you stuck? What do you want to know? SO is not a good place for a tutorial, we need specific questions.

Comment: @batman091716 Just to get you started, you _could_ put a logging statement under your `getElementsByTagName` just to ensure you've selected the correct DOM element. (e.g. `console.log("Button ->", button)`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this:

```js
  const counter = {
    cnt: 0,

    inc: function() {
      this.cnt++;
      console.log(this.cnt);
    }
  };

  const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
  button.addEventListener('click', function(){ counter.inc();}, false);
```

```html
<button>Click</button>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question

Comment: @Luca I have no idea what the question even was.

Comment: The OP asked for a way to debug the code, not for a solution, but for some reason, this answer was it...

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change the last line of JS to 

  `button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);`

When you use `counter.inc()` you are actually invoking the function immediately. The 2nd argument to the `addEventListener` should be a function, but you've supplied the result of `counter.inc()` as the 2nd argument.

Comment: This, although being an issue, doesn't make the code work

Comment: @Luca that may be due to the `cnt++` line, which is looking for a global variable `cnt`. It should be `counter.cnt++`.

Comment: Or rather `this.cnt`

Answer (score 0):

- Use JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/xm4rLckk/
- Set breakpoints in the browser in the developer tools
- Use "debugger;" statements - these are breakpoints - e.g.

  `var cnt = 0;
  debugger;
  cnt++;
  debugger;`